# GWT HtmlPanel filled with nbsp; characters (GWT's SafeHTML?)

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I'm using GWT 2.5 in one of my new projects and ran into a small obstacle.
The previous versions of GWT had SafeHTML disabled for the HTMLPanel which meant that if I put a large block of text in an HTMLPanel, it would respond like normal HTML, all double+ spaces would be removed and all newlines would be removed.
With GWT 2.5, all my spaces are replaced with nbsp; and long lines run out of the screen ignoring all my CSS rules

```
<ui:style>
    .justify {
        text-align: justify;    
    }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.justify}">

LARGE BLOCK OF TEXT THAT 
SOMETIMES GOES FAR OUT OF MY IDE AND OTHER TIMES
ONLY DO
THIS

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

The above example would look the following in GWT 2.4 (obviously justified):

```
LARGE BLOCK OF TEXT THAT 
SOMETIMES GOES FAR OUT OF 
MY IDE AND OTHER TIME 
ONLY DO THIS
```

In GWT2.5, the above example would look like this (with all spaces replaced with "& nbsp;" causing it to overflow its container even with wordwrap enabled):

```
LARGE BLOCK OF TEXT THAT 
SOMETIMES GOES FAR OUT OF MY IDE AND OTHER TIMES
ONLY DO
THIS
```

Any idea how to disable SafeHTML in GWT 2.5 for HTMLPanels or any alternative ideas on how I can put "natural HTML" inside my page without having my spaces replaced with "& nbsp;" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from Google Support after logging a bug, who said they can not reproduce the issue I'm having and suggested I have a look at what spaces my code contains (something very obvious which I never thought about).
It turns out my IDE, for some strange reason, is adding U+00A0 type spaces instead of U+0020 which is then converted to nbsp;

So if you do see nbsp; in your output, have a look at what type of spaces your IDE is inserting. A big thanks to Google Support for pointing this out!!

Comment: Kudos! for following up and posting your answer diligently!!! You might as well edit your question title to reflect the problem correctly.